# Cannot set text for form element using Watir in Ruby

Tags: ruby, automation, automated-tests, watir, web-testing

I have just started tinkering with watir after having successfully written some code to interact with a small web site hosted on my laptop using mechanize. But I am struggling to get watir to work at all.

```
require 'watir-webdriver'

b = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
b.goto('https://dev.mitdev.org.uk/login')
body = b.body
body.forms.each do |f|
  p f.name
  f.text_field(:name, 'IDToken1').wait_until_present(5).set('test')
end
```

I find that printing f.name works and I see that the login form is called "Login". But if I add the line to set the text I get a timeout.

Looking at FF I can see that the form has rendered so I'm puzzled as to why I can't seem to interact with it.

I've tried other methods of setting the values like:

```
body.text_field(:name => 'IDToken2').wait_until_present(5).set('Password')
```

But to no avail.

The tutorials online make this look so easy that I suspect I'm just making a rookie blunder and am too tired to see it.

---

Thanks for the reply. As for the exception, I'm seeing it is not rendered unless I put in the wait and a timeout if I do. If there is a way of forcing it to tell me my syntax is in error I would appreciate knowing how to do that.

Here is the form:

```
<form id="Login" name="Login" action="/login" method="post">
    <div class="sign-in">
        <fieldset>
            <legend class="form-title heading-large">Sign in</legend>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label  class="form-label" for="IDToken1">
                    User ID
                </label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="IDToken1" id="IDToken1" value="" maxlength="50" tabindex="1" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="form-label" for="IDToken2">
                    Password
                </label>
                <input type="hidden" id="goto" name="goto" value=""/>
                <input class="form-control" type="password" name="IDToken2" id="IDToken2" value="" maxlength="100" autocomplete="off" tabindex="2" />
                <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value=" deleted ">
            </div>
        </fieldset>
        <nav class="module-content-navigation">
            <input name="Login.Submit" type="submit" class="button" value="Sign in" tabindex="3" />
            <ul class="content-navigation__secondary">
                <li>
                    <a href="/forgotten-password" tabindex="4">Forgotten password</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <input name="IDButton" type="hidden" style="display: none;">
</form>
```

I've discovered a good tutorial online that has showed me how to use a hash to further qualify the address of the element but I'm still having no luck with this form:

```
b = Watir::Browser.new
b.goto('https://dev.mitdev.org.uk/login')
b.wait(3)
b.text_field(:class => 'form-control',
             :type => 'text',
             :name => 'IDToken1',
             :id => 'IDToken1').set('test')
```

I'm still getting an exception for a timeout or with no wait:

```
[remote server] file:///var/folders/f4/6vwp2t_d75v803226gs84v100000gp/T/webdriver-profile20160612-12708-sjjxdp/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:10092:in `fxdriver.preconditions.visible': Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError)
    from [remote server] file:///var/folders/f4/6vwp2t_d75v803226gs84v100000gp/T/webdriver-profile20160612-12708-sjjxdp/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12644:in `DelayedCommand.prototype.checkPreconditions_'
    from [remote server] file:///var/folders/f4/6vwp2t_d75v803226gs84v100000gp/T/webdriver-profile20160612-12708-sjjxdp/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12661:in `DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h'
    from [remote server] file:///var/folders/f4/6vwp2t_d75v803226gs84v100000gp/T/webdriver-profile20160612-12708-sjjxdp/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12666:in `DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_'
    from [remote server] file:///var/folders/f4/6vwp2t_d75v803226gs84v100000gp/T/webdriver-profile20160612-12708-sjjxdp/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12608:in `DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/<'
```

Zeroing in a little more, this prints the id of the text field:

```
p b.text_field(:type => 'text',
             :name => 'IDToken1',
             :id => 'IDToken1').id
```

but this fails to set the text:

```
b.text_field(:type => 'text',
             :name => 'IDToken1',
             :id => 'IDToken1').when_present(5).set('test')
```

This is looking more and more like something to do with the page rather than my grasp of water syntax:

```
p b.text_field(:name => /Token1/).name
p b.text_field(:type => 'text',
             :name => 'IDToken1',
             :id => 'IDToken1').id
p b.text_field(:name => /Token1/).exists?
b.text_field(:name => /Token1/).double_click
b.text_field(:name => /Token1/).set 'test'
```

Gives me this output that shows the element clearly exists but I see this weird "scroll" stack trace for the double click.

```
"IDToken1"
"IDToken1"
true
[remote server] file:///var/folders/f4/6vwp2t_d75v803226gs84v100000gp/T/webdriver-profile20160612-2812-w3soqr/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:11072:in `FirefoxDriver.prototype.mouseMoveTo': Offset within element cannot be scrolled into view: (5, 17.5): [object HTMLInputElement] (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::MoveTargetOutOfBoundsError)
    from [remote server] file:///var/folders/f4/6vwp2t_d75v803226gs84v100000gp/T/webdriver-profile20160612-2812-w3soqr/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12661:in `DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h'
    from [remote server] file:///var/folders/f4/6vwp2t_d75v803226gs84v100000gp/T/webdriver-profile20160612-2812-w3soqr/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12666:in `DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_'
    from [remote server] file:///var/folders/f4/6vwp2t_d75v803226gs84v100000gp/T/webdriver-profile20160612-2812-w3soqr/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12608:in `DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/<'
    from /Users/atkinsb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:70:in `assert_ok'
    from /Users/atkinsb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:34:in `initialize'
    from /Users/atkinsb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:78:in `new'
    from /Users/atkinsb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:78:in `create_response'
    from /Users/atkinsb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:90:in `request'
    from /Users/atkinsb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `call'
    from /Users/atkinsb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:649:in `raw_execute'
    from /Users/atkinsb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:627:in `execute'
    from /Users/atkinsb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:419:in `mouseMoveTo'
    from /Users/atkinsb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/mouse.rb:71:in `move_to'
    from /Users/atkinsb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/mouse.rb:81:in `move_if_needed'
    from /Users/atkinsb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/mouse.rb:40:in `double_click'
    from /Users/atkinsb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/action_builder.rb:363:in `block in perform'
    from /Users/atkinsb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/action_builder.rb:362:in `each'
    from /Users/atkinsb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/action_builder.rb:362:in `perform'
    from /Users/atkinsb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.9.1/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:147:in `block in double_click'
    from /Users/atkinsb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.9.1/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:598:in `element_call'
    from /Users/atkinsb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.9.1/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:147:in `double_click'
```

Feels like I'm getting closer to the problem:

```
p b.text_field(:name => /Token1/).exists?
p b.text_field(:id => /Token1/).visible?
p b.text_field(:name => /Token1/).present?
```

This show false for visible and present but true for exists.

Why this element is invisible to watir while visible to me is the next question I must answer...

Comment: It would help to provide the exception that you are seeing as well as the HTML you are working with. `.wait_until_present(5).set('test')` isn't a valid syntax, it should be `when_present(5).set('test')`. However, that would result in an undefined method error rather than a timeout.

Comment: Thanks Justin, I have added a lot more detail now

Comment: The exception says that the element is not visible. When you run the script can you seen the text field? Are you sure there isn't an action that must be performed before the text field is visible to a person?

Comment: That's what has me stumped. I can plainly see the text fields in the browser. If I set a wait of 120 and click in the text box I can enter text manually, even tab to the password field but watir insists it's not visible. One odd thing I have noticed is that there is a banner across the top of the page advising me that the site uses cookies but there is no x to close it. I don't know if that would cause this...

Comment: That is likely your issue, if the banner is blocking the textfield then watir has no way of clicking it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Woo!  Finally...

So the Selenium java code gave me the right direction and I have managed to fill the form like this:

```
b.element(:xpath => "//*[contains(@id,'_tid1')]").send_keys('user')    
b.element(:xpath => "//*[contains(@id,'_tid2')]").send_keys('password')
b.element(:name => "Login.Submit").click
```

Comment: Does this mean that the element you were looking for not the one in the provided HTML? I don't see any id attribute that contains "_tid1". Note that this can be written more succinctly as `b.element(id: /_tid1/).send_keys('user')`

Comment: Hi justin, Thanks for pointing out the missing elements. I grabbed the HTML form view source for page and it did not copy the hidden fields that I can see in the dev tools. I didn't notice. Eventually the problem was traced to the developers putting in some java script that could only be addressed by the xpath above.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried your script. Its working at my end

```
require 'watir-webdriver'

b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
b.goto 'file:///D:/WORKSPACE/Learning/demo1.html'
b.text_field(:name, 'IDToken1').when_present(5).set('test')
```

but not for form and body.

Answer (score 0):

```
p b.text_field(:name => /Token1/).exists?
p b.text_field(:id => /Token1/).visible?
```

These two lines helped me. Thanks.